# Is it possible to store integer value in localStorage like in Javascript objects and extract it without typecasting?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

When I assign integer value to localStorage item

```
localStorage.setItem('a',1)
```

and check its type

```
typeof(localStorage.a)
"string"
```

it returns **string**, I can typecast it to **int** for my use

```
parseInt(localStorage.a)
```

My question is it possible to store integer value inside localStorage as I can do for Javascript objects without typecasting?

```
a={};
a.number=1;
typeof(a.number)
"number"
```

Comment: LocalStorage can only store string values.

Comment: That's not typecasting, that's conversion. JavaScript doesn't have typecasting (since JavaScript doesn't have typed variables).

Comment: @nickalchemist: Yes, you can store an integer value in localStorage and get it back out (as an integer). See my answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> My question is it possible to store integer value inside localStorage as I can do for Javascript objects without typecasting?

No.

> Storage objects are simple key-value stores, similar to objects, but they stay intact through page loads.  The keys can be strings or integers, **but the values are always strings**. [[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: which means each time I need to typecast it to do mathematical calculations?

Comment: Yup (assuming you can't do the calculation on the string itself, which you likely can't, and even more likely shouldn't).

Comment: I solved that problem with decimal numbers like this:: If I have a local variable named x with a value 1.54 I will store it in the local storage as x*100 ( which is 154 ) And then when I will read it from the local storage I will read it and devide by 100 . That's way I could have the numbers kept after the dot.

Answer (score 15):

Actually you can, if we agree that parsing is not the same as typecasting :

```
let val = 42;
localStorage.answer = JSON.stringify(val);
let saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.answer);
console.log( saved === val ); // true
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0jay71d/) since over-protected stacksnippets don't allow localStorage.

For simplicity, you should anyway always stringify to JSON what you are saving in localStorage, this way you don't have to think about what you are saving / retrieving, and you will avoid `"[object Object]"` being saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in numeric format using:

```
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify({
  //Insert Number(value)
  number: Number(1)
}));

// After get item
var object = localStorage.getItem('object');
console.log(JSON.parse(object));
```

Comment: Even if you don't directly parse the _value_ to int, the JSON is a string and when you parse the object, you parse its values. JSON knows, that that particular value is an integer and will parse it automatically to an int but it still parses it.

Comment: I didn't say, it's not working, I just said that it doesn't fulfil the requirements of no conversion.

Comment: Ah yes I understand, your point is perfect. I will leave this answer here in case a person like me is looking for something in that sense, which was my case! thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad, I could convey my point

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store an integer in localStorage, but since it will be converted into a string, how do you actually know it was an integer? The question is not rhetorical. *Storing an integer* in localStorage is one thing (and easily accomplished), but *knowing it's supposed to be an integer* when you retrieve it is a different matter altogether. Not only do you have to keep track of the storage key value, you must also keep track of the data *type*.

What we really want is a mechanism that allows us to treat storage almost the same way we treat variables. If I am working with an integer, a float, a bigint, a string, a date, an array, a Boolean or an object then we would like to shove it into localStorage and get it back out. No conversion. No muss and no fuss.

This is precisely what [**localDataStorage**](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage) does. (NOTE: I am the author.) The library transparently sets/gets key values using data "types" such as **Array**, **BigInt**, **Boolean**, **Date**, **Float**, **Integer**, **Object** and **String**. Store an integer, get it back. Working with dates, bigints or floats? No problem. And if you need to store arrays in localStorage, you can easily do so, as well as add and remove elements. Again, **localDataStorage** does all the heavy lifting for you. Let's have a look:

Include the library:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/macmcmeans/localDataStorage@master/localDataStorage-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Instantiate a namespaced copy:

```js
const lds = localDataStorage( 'myapp-storage' );
```

Toss an integer in storage...

```js
lds.set( 'myIntKey', 467 );
```

and get it back out:

```js
let myInt = lds.get( 'myIntKey' );
console.log( myInt );
> 467
```

Ensure the data type was preserved:

```js
typeof myInt;
> "number"
```

You can also check data types with the library:

```js
lds.showtype( 'myIntKey' );
> "integer"

lds.isinteger( 'myIntKey' );
> true

lds.isnumber( 'myIntKey' );
> true
```

And of course we have some helper functions:

```js
lds.haskey( 'myIntKey' );
> true

lds.hasval( 467 );
> true

lds.hastype( "integer" );
> true
```

The library also 1) provides lightweight data obfuscation; 2) intelligently compresses strings (to save storage space); 3) facilitates robust lookup including query by key (name), query by (key) value and query by existence (boolean check); 4) enforces segmented shared storage within the same domain by prefixing keys; and 5) responds to localStorage change events on the same page/tab that fired them. [/end glossyBrochure]