# LocalStorage Saving as Strings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a speeding application that asks the user to input a pre-defined speed limit through an input, I have used local storage to store the number but it stores it like "number" instead of just the number it places quotation marks around them making it a string and useless in  my application.

Here is the JS

```
 var limit = 20;
 var limitfield = document.getElementById('limit1') //Places limit1 field from HTML into variable 
 limitfield.addEventListener('input', updateStorage); //Adds eventlistener to listen to input in limit1 field then call method

 function updateStorage (){
 localStorage.setItem('limitfield', limitfield.value); //After obtaining the input from eventlistener store the value in variable
  setPreference();
                             }

 function setPreference(){
  limit = localStorage.getItem('limitfield'); //variable created that retrieves value  
                         }
```

Comment: that's how it works. Web Storages store strings. If you need a number you can always cast with `+` operator in front of the variable or just using your variable in numeric context.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952287/is-it-possible-to-store-integer-value-in-localstorage-like-in-javascript-objects

Comment: Oh, I'm fairly new at this so I did not know. Can you tell me how to put the variable in numeric context and what do you mean with the operator?

Comment: Always store JSON format, you'll save you a lot of problems : setting : `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));`. getting : `var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.key)`

Comment: @Kaiido How do I save as a JSON format? Will it fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit = +localStorage.getItem('limitfield');` - direct type conversion

or

```
limit = localStorage.getItem('limitfield');
var otherVar = someVar - limit;
```

conversion to Number type by using your variable in numeric context (division operation).

Comment: Adding the + operator makes it a numeric format!!!
Thank you but I still do not understand, what does the "+" do exactly?

Comment: it kind of forces numerical context upon your variable and conversion occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would not have found this out by myself

Comment: well, you are welcome :)